# Series of a sequence with quadratic cosine and its limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

The task is to find $lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$, where

$$x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\sin\frac{2k+1}{k^2+k}*\sin\frac{1}{k^2+k}$$

After modifications, we get:

$$\sin\frac{2k+1}{k^2+k}*\sin\frac{1}{k^2+k} = \cos^2\frac{1}{k+1} - \cos^2\frac{1}{k}$$
And:
$$x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n(\cos^2\frac{1}{k+1} - \cos^2\frac{1}{k})$$

Here everything is correct. The problem is: how to count this series? In the answer we have, that
$$x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n(\cos^2\frac{1}{k+1} - \cos^2\frac{1}{k}) = \cos^2\frac{1}{n+1} - \cos^21$$
How we get it?

Comment: This is a telescoping sum. If you write out the terms, all will cancel apart from $\cos^2\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-\cos^2(1)$.

Comment: @A.Goodier Oh, I completely forgot about it. Thanks